# ChromeOS tabs refresh everytime they are opened

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

If I have two or more tabs open, the tab will refresh every single time that I switch between them, even if I had it open 5 seconds ago. Any ideas on how to stop this?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Do you know which channel you are on (Stable, beta, or development)? You can check by clicking on Settings | Help | More Info... (http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1086915). I haven't found an answer to your question, but I did find an old issue report (http://code.google.com/p/chromium-os/issues/detail?id=26967) and an old forum topic (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/A0k7qZsGoak). Both of these seem to have occurred for users on non-stable channels at some point in the past.

Answer (score 1):

[Issue 26967: Tabs reload when selected](http://code.google.com/p/chromium-os/issues/detail?id=26967) says :

> Fixed with change https://gerrit.chromium.org/gerrit/#change,17014

This change was merged on Feb 29, 2012.
You apparently just need to wait until this fix finds its way to your computer.

Comment: Note: I'm not too sure about the relationship between Chrome and Chromium as regarding bug fixes.

Comment: Looks like this will be the definitive answer. I am using Chromium so hopefully the next build will fix! Thanks!

Comment: It's a year later and this problem [is still common](http://bit.ly/YwctLF). Either fix bogus or never made it into Chromebook stream.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch: Try to revive it on the Chromium forums.

Comment: I don't even own a Chromebook -- and this kind of issue makes it unlikely I ever will. I'm just pointing out that no fix is in the stream. Perhaps you should give your bounty back.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch: (1) There is no way I can do that, (2) I'm not to blame for the errors of the Chromium developers, (3) I did find for the poster what his problem was.